# Continuous enrollment gap by multiple categories

Tags: sas

I have a dataset in which I must derive a case and control group for individuals that have continuous enrollment with no more than 1 gap of 45 days; 2 gaps of 10 days each won't qualify because it's more than 1 gap.

I've seen documents like the following which describe how to process dates using enrollment data: https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug01/cc/cc4017.pdf

I'm attempting to do something similar but among multiple categories. I'm just not quite certain about the approach to take. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
data History;
input patid plan lob $ aid $ eligible start end;
informat start end mmddyy10.;
format start end date9.;
cards;
1  1 MC LIS 1 10/1/2019 12/31/9999
1  2 MC LIS 1 9/1/2019 9/30/2019
1  1 MC LIS 1 10/1/2018 08/31/2019
1  . FFS LIS 1 4/1/2018 12/31/9999
1  1 MC LIS 1 4/1/2018 9/30/2018
1  . FFS noLIS 0 8/1/2015 3/31/2018
1  1 MC noLIS 0 8/1/2015 3/31/2018
2 . FFS LIS 1 12/18/2019 12/31/9999
2 3 MC LIS 1 5/1/2019 12/17/2019
2 . FFS LIS 1 5/1/2019 12/31/9999
2 3 MC LIS 1 8/1/2018 4/30/2019
2 3 MC LIS 1 7/1/2018 7/31/2018
2 . FFS LIS 1 5/1/2018 4/30/2019
3 2 MC noLIS 0 8/1/2018 12/31/9999
3 2 MC noLIS 0 8/1/2017 7/31/2018
3 . FFS noLIS 0 5/1/2017 12/31/9999
3 . FFS noLIS 0 12/1/2012 4/30/2017
3 2 MC noLIS 0 12/1/2012 4/30/2017
;
 run;
```

This dataset has:

1. patient id
2. Plan
3. Line of business (Medicare FFS or Managed Care [MC])
4. Aid category (LIS vs. noLIS)
5. Eligibility Criteria
6. Start Date
7. End Date

Want:

- I want to create 2 datasets; continuously enrolled for the calendar year with no more than 1 gap of 45 days
- By aid (LIS)--like a case vs control with the aid category being the identifier

*Result:*

Patient 1: Would fall into the case group; has only 1 gap of 30 days so it is included

Patient 2:  Would be removed since they have 2 gaps in enrollment

Patient 3: Would fall into the control group; no gap and has noLIS

Comment: Do you want to exclude rows when patient is not eligible ?  What if enrollment data shows a coverage date has overlaps of  `eligible=1` and `eligible=0` ? What aid classification is used if an overlapped coverage date has `LIS` from one plan and `noLIS` from the other?

Comment: They will be included in a separate group; a control group for non-eligible patients. There should be no overlap with aid coverage of LIS vs. nonLIS.

Comment: Patient 1 in 2018, while no gaps in coverage data, had differing eligibility (changing from no to yes on 4/1/2018).  What group classification would you expect ?  Does a patient enrollment record with `eligibility=1` ever have `aid="noLIS"` ?  What if they do ?